# check if collection contains id = (some id) where associated with a user id

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I need to check if a collection of user submitted data contains an id of that data where the user that posted that data is the same user that is authenticated and performing the request.
How can I do this with the collection methods available in eloquent?

example:

```
 public function index(){

        $user_id = Auth::id();

        if(Request::ajax()){

            $suggested_data_id = Input::get('suggested_data_id');

            $LatestSuggestions = Suggested_data::with('user')->latest()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get();

            if($LatestSuggestions->contains('id', $suggested_data_id)->where( // the user that posted that data that is found in the collection is the authenticated user )){

                return response()->json(array('latest_suggestions' => $LatestSuggestions));

            }else{

                $userLatestAddition = Suggested_data::with('user')->where('id', '=', $suggested_data_id)->get();

                return response()->json(array('latest_suggestions' => $LatestSuggestions, 'last_user_addition' => $userLatestAddition));

            }


        }

    }
```